# Modal no se muestra al poner el botón de llamada dentro de un formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap, formularios

Tenía un modal que se activaba al presionar en un enlace, pero ahora lo necesito en un botón dentro de un formulario porque necesito que ejecute un codigo php, pero este no aparece, se oscurece la pagina un segundo como si fuera a mostrarlo pero no aparece el modal.

Este es mi código:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <button name="anadirLista" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Estoy interesado</button>
</form>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Producto añadido a su lista de interés!</p>
           <p>Puede seguir navegando para añadir más productos a su lista o bien verla ahora mismo <a href="lista.php">haciendo click aquí</a> o verla más tarde en el menú superior.</p>
        </div>
    /div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Poner solo el tag **button** genera un evento **submit**, para evitar ello agregale la propiedad **type="button"**

```
<button type="button" name="anadirLista" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Estoy interesado</button>
```

Otra cosa, en el código de compartiste el ** falta cerrar con **

Comment: O mejor, que ponga el button sin form. Para poner un button no es necesario que esté dentro de un form.

Comment: Podría retirar **form** en caso no tenga funcionalidad alguna, pero es una buena práctica indicar la funcionalidad y alcance del control **button**, creo que el código que muestra es de ejemplo y minificado.

Comment: En ese caso mejor poner <input type="button"> que es el elemento botón para los formularios y además no lanza el submit.

Comment: @Kamousagi Pero necesito el formulario porque luego al presionar el botón tengo que ejecutar un código php, y sin el método Post no puedo mirar si se ha presionado el boton

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser un `<button type="button"></button>` así no genera el submit del form o cambiar el button por un `<a href="" class="btn btn-primary"></a>`, por que veo que estás usando bootstrap, y al href le agregas la funcionalidad.